# AWS, EC2, Elastic Ips and DSN Connection Strings

Tags: security, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am setting up a basic dev, qa and production environment for an app in EC2.  A dsn string to connect the web app to the database looks something like

```
jdbc:postgresql://64.210.255.235:5432/mydb
```

But here is where things break down, to be secure, I need to add the elastic ip addresses of the web heads to the database's security group, in addition to elastic ips to connect to the database via dsn.  However, EC2 apparently lets you only have 5 elastic ips?  Help, what do I do?  And please explain to me like a 6th grader, I am a developer with almost no system administration or AWS experience. For an answer I need concrete steps to make this work, not high level observations.

Comment: can't you use public dns instead of ip, i.e. `ec2-xxx-xxx-xx-xx.eu-zone.compute.amazonaws.com`?

Comment: Don't those change all the time?

Comment: An no, this does not appear to work `[ec2-user@ip-172-31-12-63 ~]$ psql -h ec2-54-201-32-191.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com`

Comment: what is your exact question? is 5 EIP limit is your concern? OR adding EIPs to the DB security group ?

Comment: they are assinged on creation and change on restart of the instance;
you may also opt to use [amazon vpc](http://aws.amazon.com/vpc/#highlights) for your private environments, but you'll have to leard those system administration tricks then.

Comment: @slayedbylucifer, first of all, good handle.  second, what Im trying to do conceptually is super simple.  I have 3 environments, 6 servers.  I want to have stable jdbc dsns that I dont have to change when the EC2 DHCP updates.  I need my web heads to talk to my db boxes and be secure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> first of all, good handle. second, what Im trying to do conceptually is super simple. I have 3 environments, 6 servers. I want to have stable jdbc dsns that I dont have to change when the EC2 DHCP updates. I need my web heads to talk to my db boxes and be secure.

2 options:

1. use VPC, so that you can have persistent privat IP for your DBs.
2. Ask amazon to increase your EIP limit by filling up [this](https://aws.amazon.com/contact-us/eip_limit_request/) form.